# Making a text field flow like a paragraph in Adobe Livecycle Designer

Tags: adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I intend to create a form using Adobe Livecycle Designer 7.00 in which I want a field to flow as does a paragraph in a text editor.

To be more specific, I have a text object before and after the text field which is contained in a subform. As there is some text before the text field, it naturally would not start from extreme left. Now when the user starts filling the field it should grow rightwards (that is easy by clciking "fit to width") however, instead of growing out of paper, it, like a parqagraph in text editor, goes to next line which starts from the exteme left of the form and continues rightwards.

Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, what you need to do is change the Subform's type to Flow Content, then changing it's Flow Direction to "Western Text".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, you can achieve this by using a floating field (if the data is coming from the backend).

You can add the pre and post dynamic data in the text object and create a floaing field in the middle of the text object.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Thanks,
Armaghan.